# Looking for a way to dispatch touch commands on android over another application

Tags: android, touch, daemon

i am looking for ways to execute touch command on a non rooted Android device. i have noticed that an Android App (some kind of automation Application ) was able to do it http://ankulua.boards.net/thread/3/daemon-installation
by installing their daemon service
the way it works i believe is that : 
ADB permission to start the service, "file is copied to the location of your device /data/local/tmp" and once the service is started it is ready to accept command sent from their Ankulula, and able to create touch event event user doesn't have the root access.

does anyone knows how this is implemented, or are there any other ways of doing it -> not using ADB/ computer/ ROOT to create the same /similar result

any insight or direction to library or resource will be really appreciated
Thanks

Comment: what have you done so far - in code?

Comment: um.. hasn't able to accomplish anything solid, 
i have the idea, not sure if it works

Comment: since i am not a C developer, so i am starting everything from example online. so far i have managed to start a process from adb, and android App able to press a button which call the background process, and display a msg to the log.
and now i am kind of stuck at "calling system("input tap 300 200") return error caught signal 17.
i have the idea, not sure if it works
if a daemon process started via adb, would the process be able to start another shell script call like "input swipe 100 100 200 200 500" and just like as if it is called from ADB.

Comment: finally i got it completed and made it into a release APP.